# Can a Flame Ionization Detector be used with H2 as carrier gas?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

In a Gas Chromatography instrument can a Flame Ionization Detector be used with $\ce{H2}$ as carrier gas?

My intuition says no, because I'd be afraid you'd set the whole column on fire (or worse).

Is this right? Or can an FID be used even with $\ce{H2}$ carrier gas safely?

Comment: It works see https://www.sepscience.com/Techniques/GC/Articles/208-/GC-Solutions-11-The-Flame-Ionization-Detector

Comment: @MaxW Thanks. But the article does not explicitly mention an FID working with an H2 carrier gas, does it? Maybe I missed it. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, try http://www.restek.com/Landing-Pages/Content/gen_B008 and try goggle yourself...

Comment: Your intuition is wrong: to set the column on fire, you would need to have a mixture of H2 and O2 within the column. As long as the flow of hydrogen is maintained through the column and prevents entry of oxygen, there is no risk. (Think of the same situation with a gas cooker burner: there is no flame in the tubing carrying methane to the burner.)

Comment: @MaxW is correct; further, it is common practice.